# Error on the display statement even after importing the package

Tags: java

I can't seem to understand what is the problem with this code. I'm new to classes in Java. I made a new Java Class here. I've tried almost everything but the error on the lines below my constructor are really getting annoying now. Can someone please help me what is wrong here?

P.s the main class is completely empty and the lines in bold are the ones where the compiler shows errors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class calculator extends FinalConsole {

        float x; 
        float y; 
        float v;
        float w;
        float z;
        char op;


        Scanner in= new Scanner(System. in); 
        public calculator(){
        System.out.println("You have selected calculator interface");
        }

        **System.out.println("Enter the number of digits: ");
        int values;
        values=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Select your funcion");
        op = in.next().charAt(0);**


        **if (values==2){**
        System.out.println("Enter first number: "); 
        x= in.nextFloat( );
        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        y=in.nextFloat();

            switch (op){

                case '+':
                 z=x+y;
                System.out.println("sum is:" +z);
                break;

                case '-':
                z = x-y;
                System.out.println("sum is:" +z);
                break;

                case '/':
                    z=y/x;
        System.out.println("sum is:" +z);

                break;
                case '*':
                z=x*y;
        System.out.println("sum is:" +z);
                break;
                default:
                System.out.println("Invalid operator");
        }
        }

         **if (values==3){**
        System.out.println("Enter first number: "); 
        x= in.nextFloat( );

        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        y=in.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Enter third number: "); 
        v= in.nextFloat( );

        switch(op){
            case '+':
            z=w+x+y;
        System.out.println("sum is:" +z);
            break; 

            case '-':
            z=x-y;
        System.out.println("sum is:" +z);
            break;

            case '/':

             z=y/x;
        System.out.println("sum is:" +z);
            break;

            case '*':
            z=w*x*y;
        System.out.println("sum is:" +z);
            break;


            default:
            System.out.println("Invalid operator");
            break;

        }
         }

         **if (values==4){**

        System.out.println("Enter first number: "); 
        x= in.nextFloat( );

        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        y=in.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Enter third number: "); 
        v= in.nextFloat( );

        System.out.println("Enter fourth number: "); 
        w= in.nextFloat( );

         switch (op){

             case '+':
            z=v+w+x+y;
        System.out.println("sum is:" +z); 
             break;

             case '-':
            z=x-y;
        System.out.println("sum is:" +z);
            break; 

             case '/':
            z=y/x;
            System.out.println("sum is:" +z);
            break;

             case '*':
            z=v*w*x*y;
        System.out.println("sum is:" +z);
            break;

             default:
            System.out.println("Invalid operator");
            break;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: it should be inside some method like this `public void calculator(){
        System.out.println("You have selected calculator interface");
        }
`

Comment: @PavneetSingh: Isn't that a constructor?

Comment: yeah , didn't notice the class name , so no `void`  and put rest of the code in a method

Comment: for best practice , follow the java convention , class name always starts with an uppercase alphabet

Answer (score 0):

you should put your statements in blocks or methods, like following

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class calculator  {
    float x;
    float y;
    float v;
    float w;
    float z;
    char op;
    Scanner in= new Scanner(System. in);
    public calculator(){
        System.out.println("You have selected calculator interface");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of digits: ");
        int values;
        values = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Select your funcion");
        op = in.next().charAt(0);
    }
}
```